# Independence of Brownian Motion with respect to a stopping time

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $B_t$ be a brownian motion, $B_0=0$, and $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$.
Now, let's build the following stopping time:
\begin{equation}
  T = \inf \{ t \geq 0 : |B_t + \gamma t| = 1 \}.
\end{equation}
If $\gamma = 0$, how would you argue that $B$ and $T$ are independents?

Comment: Could you please clarify, what do you mean by the independence here? For example, 
$$
  \mathsf P(B_1\geq 1,T\geq 2) = 0 \neq \mathsf P(B_1\geq 1)\mathsf P(T\geq 2)
$$

Comment: *how would you argue that B and T are independent*... I would not, they are not.

Comment: If $\gamma = 0$ it is really just a simple consequence of symmetry, since $-B_t$ is also a brownian motion.